# Page access only from a specific page in wordpress website

Tags: pages, redirect, child-pages, buttons

I would like to know if it possible to have a page that open if and only if the visitor comes from a specific page (which in my case would be the homepage).
So for example, the visitors land on the homepage, by clicking on a button the targeted page open. But if someone tries to visit the specific page without clicking on the button from the homepage, He would be redirected to another page :
If visitor goes to Homepage and the visitor clicks button -> Specific page url opens
If the visitor land on the specific page -> redirected to another page or the home page.

I am sorry if it is a bit confused, I hope you will be able to understand my question.

Thank you for your help.
Peter

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible by checking the referer on your target page before rendering the page.  There may be a better way to solve your task, however, if you want to share more details.  Setting a cookie, passing a parameter with the URL - there is usually more than one way to address a problem.

In answer to your question, `wp_get_referer()` will return the URL for the page the user arrived from or false if from the same page.  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_referer/

If your home page URL is 'http://mypage.local', this would work.  Again, this is probably not the best approach for your project:

```
$referer = wp_get_referer();

if ( 'http://mypage.local' !== $referer ) {
  // User arrived from another source so send them away!
  wp_redirect( 'http://mypage.local/otherpage' );
  exit;
}
```